# I got an error in function `yylex': lex.yy.c:(.text+0x2ac): undefined reference

Tags: c, compiler-construction, flex-lexer, yacc, lex

I am new with lex and yacc, and I am following the ["lex & yacc 1992" book](https://books.google.at/books?id=vsHcnR4kXIAC&printsec=frontcover&source=gbs_ge_summary_r&cad=0#v=onepage&q&f=false).

I am working in an example in chapter 3, and I have an error in the compiling process, but I couldn't find a solution;
here is the code:

the lex file.l :

```
%{

#include "y.tab.h"
#include "symboletable.h"
#include <math.h>
extern int yylavl;

%}


%%
([0-9]+|([0-9]*\.[0-9]+)([eE][-+]?[0-9]+)?) {
            yylval.dval = atof(yytext);
            return NUMBER;
        }
[ \t] ;       /* ignore whitespace */ 

[A-Za-z][A-Za-z0-9]* { /* return symbol pointer */
            yylval.symp = symlook(yytext);
            return NAME;
        }
"$" { return 0; }
\n |  
. return yytext[0];

%%
```

and here the yacc file.y

```
%{
#include "symboletable.h"
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>     /* C declarations used in actions */
int yylex();
void yyerror(const char *s);
%}

%union {
    double dval;
    struct symtab *symp;
}

%token <symp> NAME
%token <dval> NUMBER

%left '+' '-'
%left '*' '/'
%nonassoc UMINUS

%type <dval> expression
%%

statement_list : statement '\n'
               | statement_list statement '\n'
               ;

statement  : expression   { printf("= %g\n", $1); } 
           | NAME '=' expression {$1->value = $3; }
           ;


expression : NAME {$$ = $1->value; }
           | expression '+' expression {$$ = $1 + $3; }
           | expression '-' expression {$$ = $1 - $3; }
           | expression '*' expression {$$ = $1 * $3; }
           | expression '/' expression
                {   if ($3 ==0.0)
                        yyerror("divide by zero");
                    else
                        $$ = $1 / $3; 
                }
           | '-' expression %prec UMINUS {$$ = -$2; }
           | '(' expression ')' {$$ = $2; }
           | NUMBER
           ;
%%
```

according to the example in the book, I need to write a symbol table routines, to get the string and allocate dynamic space for the string, here the file.h

the symboletable.h

```
#define NSYMS 20 /* maximum number of symbols */
struct symtab {
        char *name;
        double value;
} symtab[NSYMS];

struct symtab *symlook();
```

and the symboletable.pgm:

```
/* look up a symbol table entry, add if not present */
struct symtab *
symlook(s)
char *s;
{
    char *p;
    struct symtab *sp;
    for (sp = symtab; sp < &symtab[NSYMS]; sp++){
        /* is it already here ? */
        if (sp->name && !strcmp(sp->name, s))
            return sp;

        /* is it free */
        if (!sp->name){
            sp->name = strdup(s);
            return sp;
        }
        /* otherwise continue to next */
    }
    yyerror("Too many symbols");
    exit(1);    /* cannot continue */
} /* symlook */
```

now when I run the following command:

```
yacc -d file.y 
lex file.l 
cc -c lex.yy.c -o newfile -ll
cc -o new y.tab.c lex.yy.c -ly -ll
```

but here the error I got:

> /tmp/ccGnPAO2.o: In function `yylex': lex.yy.c:(.text+0x2ac):
>   undefined reference to`symlook' collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit
>   status

so, why I got that error, I am totally follow the example ?

Comment: Why are you writing such ancient code? I was totally lost with your definiton of `symlook()`. Update your book. Or only your code, that style for parameter declaration is too old for you, you are a new generation.

Comment: `struct symtab *symlook(s) char *s { }` is [K&R C](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_(programming_language)#K&R_C) - **ancient** is a suitable description. Since ANSI C, this can be written as `struct symtab* symlook(char *s) { }`. Concerning the proto `struct symtab *symlook();`: it might work but even better would be a proto with correct signature: `struct symtab* symlook(char*);`.

Comment: Although K&R C is ancient, a lot of C compilers seem still to support it. (May be, a tribute to the inventors...) I believe, the syntax is not your issue. What makes me suspicious: If your file with implementation of `symlook()` is really named `symboletable.pgm` (like stated in your question) then you forgot to mention it in your lines for compile and link. Hence, the link error instead of syntax error. Btw. `.pgm` is not prohibited but rather unusual for a c source file. Why not suffix `.c`?

Comment: Did you know that you can add regular C code after the second `%%` of the `.lex` file? If you move the implementation of `symlook()` to that place your issue should be fixed as well.

Comment: How are you compiling the file with `symlook` in and linking it with the other code? Seems to be missing from the commands listed

Comment: I am kinda new with using lex and yacc, so I didn't want to make changes make it worse, actually I was thinking of add the code as a normal c style in the third part in lex file, I just wanted to follow the book instruction as a beginner, Okay I will check these options.

Answer (score 0):

You need to include your symbol table implementation in your compilation command. Otherwise, how is the linker going to find that code?